# Reading data field value of a linq query returns dynamic data type

Tags: c#, linq

I have the function below. How do I loop through the dataset return as dynamic data type and read each value of each data field?

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetMainDataSet(string dbConn, string rawSQL)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext db_ops = new ApplicationDbContext(dbConn))
    {
        var tMain = db_ops.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(rawSQL);

        //how to access the resultset?


        return tMain.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. Add a generic parameter and let the caller tell you which data type they expect. eg `GetMainDataSet<int>(...)`.

Comment: why not use EF and make it map the database to your class-structure?

Comment: I am reading a list of raw SQLs from somewhere and creating the class structure for each of these SQLs is time consuming. Plus, those SQLs can add or delete columns anytime.

Comment: Avoid `dynamic` like the plague. It will cause you more pain than gain.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with the simpler DbDataReader approach

```
public static DbDataReader GetMainDataSet(string dbConn, string rawSQL)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db_ops = new ApplicationDbContext(dbConn);
    var connection = db_ops.Database.Connection;
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = rawSQL;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    connection.Open();

    var result = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    return result;
}
```

To call:

```
var reader = RaxDbReader.GetMainDataSet(app_db_str, value.ToString());

while (reader.Read())
{
     var columnName = reader.GetName(0);
     var columnType = reader.GetFieldType(0).ToString();
     var columnValue = reader.GetString(0);
     // Perform an action with the data retrieved
     Console.WriteLine("Name = " + columnName);
     Console.WriteLine("Type = " + columnType);
     Console.WriteLine("Value = " + columnValue);
}
reader. Close();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?